# Xamarin Forms RemovePage unexpected result

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

I have the following page flow in my navigation page: (1)LoginPage->(2)ForgotPasswordPage->(3)PasswordSentPage

The moment I leave (2) I want it of the NavigationStack, so that the back button returns to (1).

I tried in (2):

```
InsertPageBefore(pwSentPage, this); 
await Navigation.PopAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This results in the right page, because the title is correct, but the content is that of (1). If I press the back button, the content stays, but the title changes...

I also tried in (3):

```
protected override void OnAppearing ()
{
    base.OnAppearing ();
    var prevPage = Navigation.NavigationStack.FirstOrDefault (p => p is ForgotPasswordPage);
    Navigation.RemovePage (prevPage);
}
```

Pressing the back button here shows me a blank screen like this:

[image: Empty screen]

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making an assumption here, but because you appear to be using material design and `RemovePage`, you're likely experiencing [this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37462). Give the latest 2.1 prerelease a try and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: I hope this is indeed the solution. I'm not sure about using a pre-release though. I'll just wait a little.

Comment: Yes this was working, getting some other issues though. But for this thread, it is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use `PushModalAsync`?

You could put this on the `Login` page, and use this call to show the `ForgotPasswordPage`.

When it has completed, it will return back to the `Login` page and will no longer be in the navigation stack.

You can then navigate to the `PasswordSentPage` from the `Login` page if desired afterwards?

After the dismissal of the `ForgotPasswordPage`, it will no longer be in the navigation stack.

Either use `messaging` or a `TaskCompletionSource` to respond specifically to some type of response or action to then trigger, i.e. navigation to the `PasswordSentPage` if required (should the page had not been cancelled).

Comment: This would result in a flashing screen and is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question, you can remove the page from the `NavigationStack`.
This works in my Project as it should:

FirstPage -> PushAsync -> SecondPage -> PushAsync -> ThirdPage

And in ThirdPage:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var secondPage = Navigation.NavigationStack.FirstOrDefault(p => p is SecondPage);
    Navigation.RemovePage(secondPage);
}
```

The backnavigation, either with the backbutton or in Ccde with `PopAsync`, shows the FirstPage.

Please check your Code. Above solution should work in your case.
Maybe you do something in your `OnAppearing` method. I created a testproject with just These 3 pages, and no other stuff in it, and it worked.